# NuGet feed hosting options including MyGet

Tags: package, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, myget

I have been investigating options for NuGet feed hosts.

Currently, we use TeamCity to build/publish packages to TC's built-in server.  For a Visual Studio package-source pointed to TC, we've found that the subscription/update process to be painfully slow -- even though our developer workstations are within the same local subnet and we have only a few dozen packages.

Other package-feed options I know about :

1. nw share
2. internal web-server(s) based on NuGet.Server
3. MyGet
4. ProGet

Does anyone have enterprise-level experience with any of these solutions ?

MyGet looks very promising, but one cause for concern is that ( at least according to their website ) only around 1500 feeds are active.  If MyGet had truly caught on, it would seem that this should be 150,000 or so.

Also: is there anything in the NuGet world similar to Maven's concept of a local-only "snapshot" package engine and feed server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As one of the founders of MyGet let me take this question :-) We indeed have around 1.500 feeds hosted on our *public* website, we also have some enterprise users who have their own domains and are not listed here. Feel free to contact us if you require more info or want to be in touch with one of them. We're also open for just a chat so feel free.

In the Gallery (http://www.myget.org/gallery) we have famous projects like SignalR, RavenDB, Glimpse and the ASP.NET team is pushing their nightlies as well.

In the field, we see a lot of "self hosted" solutions based on NuGet.Server but these are typically smaller installations. Just as with network shares, it lacks a bit in performance when too many packages are in that feed.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to performance, our newest 2.0 release of ProGet underwent some performance enhancements, mainly caching of LDAP credentials and the fact that package data is now cached in the database, so adding packages doesn't have to rebuild the full index of packages (where previously if combined with something like 1000s of packages stored by RedGate's Deployment Manager, it would have slowed things a bit).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add two products to the list.

- Sonatype's Nexus pro - If you are running a mixed Java/.NET shop it might be a good
  alternative. http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/features. I'm not sure here but since Nexus is a maven tool from beginning it would be plausible that it has some kind of snapshot support for nuget feeds as well, however not local.
- Teamcity - it has built in support for nuget that integrates and works well with teamcity but it (version 7.1.4) does not support all native nuget operations like managing packages from outside teamcity and there is no easy way to proxy other feeds nor support for multiple feeds. http://jetbrains.com/teamcity

Comment: TeamCity is a bust as a NuGet package server. Works great for a handful of packages, but once up to a couple dozen it slows down considerably. We had recent experience of Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager taking over 2 hrs to resolve dependencies on adding a new package with a complex set of dependencies. Once we moved all our packages to MyGet this same operation was 2 mins.

Comment: Stay away from Sonatype Nexus. It has not supported NuGet 3.0 since March 2013 (See unfixed major [bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6158)), which is the reason I am reading this question.